# How to integrate VVVVEBJS with a Django project

Tags: django

I have an existing Django project, and I want to integrate the VVVVEBJS library (https://github.com/towfiqi/VVVVEBJS) to provide a drag-and-drop website builder functionality. VVVVEBJS is a JavaScript library, and I'm not sure about the best approach to integrate it with my Django project.

Here are the steps I've taken so far:

However, I'm unsure about how to properly initialize and use the VVVVEBJS library within my Django views and templates. I'm also not sure about the best way to handle user-generated content from VVVVEBJS and save it to the database.

Can someone please guide me through the steps required to integrate VVVVEBJS with my Django project? I'd appreciate any tips, examples, or resources that can help me achieve this integration successfully.